# How to convert "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" sql Timestamp?

Tags: java

I have a string `s= "2019-10-11T12:12:23.234Z";`

I am trying to convert into `TimeStamp` by using below code

```
Timestamp ts = Timestamp.valueOf(beforeConversionStartDate);
```

getting error like:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]
```

Answer (score 3):

In Java 8+, use `Instant` to parse the text, then convert to `Timestamp`:

```
String s = "2019-10-11T12:12:23.234Z";
Timestamp ts = Timestamp.from(Instant.parse(s));
System.out.println(ts);
```

In Java 7 or earlier, use `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
String s = "2019-10-11T12:12:23.234Z";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(format.parse(s).getTime());
System.out.println(ts);
```

*Output (I'm in Eastern time zone)*

```
2019-10-11 08:12:23.234
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error clearly explains the format of the date you are trying to provide in the timestamp is illegal.

This is a non illegal format that `valueOf()` accepts, *2019-10-11 12:12:23.234*,

```
String s = "2019-10-11 12:12:23.234";
Timestamp ts = Timestamp.valueOf(s);

if (ts != null)
    System.out.println("ts initialized");
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply, i  am getting string in same format ..i want to convert  string into sql time stamp

Comment: That explains why, not how to parse the given string value.

Comment: you're right , checkout Andreas answer